# Pinning a view to the bottom with dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a UILabel that can have a variable number of lines and hence height. I want to pin this label to the bottom of my view like so:

[image]

If the text forces the label to expand I want the label to remain the same height from the bottom of the view (about one line of text showing) but allow the label to expand downwards (it is in a scrollview). I could of course pin the UILabel to the top of the screen but then that would give different results depending on the screen size. How can I achieve this result? Is it possible with IB or will I have to do it programatically?

Comment: show your view hierarchy and constraint you added to scrollview.

Comment: just pin it to the bottem, left and right. Give it a numberOfRows to 0 and leave the height. This should work

Comment: @kex what's in what? Please show us the view hierarchy.

Comment: @Mr.UB I was yes. Just accepted the answer below. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pin the label to the top (of the content view that will be scrolled) and then create and outlet for the constraint that pins the label to the top (Or just programatically create it to have the reference)

Once you have the reference just set the constant of the constraint to the height of the screen in viewDidLoad.

```
constraint.constant = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.height - heightFromBottom
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using following steps:

1. Take a scroll view and add constraints(top, bottom, trailing, leading) = 0, to the Superview.
2. Add a UIView inside the Scroll and add constraints (top, bottom, trailing, leading) = 0 , to the Scroll View.
3. Set Height and Width Constraint of the UIView equal to the Superview(i.e. Main View, self.view).

[image: Height and Width Constraint of the UIView]

4. Select the height constraint of the of the UIView and set its Priority to `750`.

   [image: UIView Priority to <code>750</code>]
5. Add a Label to the bottom of the UIView and set its constraints (bottom, top, trailing, and leading) to the UIView.
6. Set the height of the label `greater than equal to`. (you have already done this, although we do no need this).
7. Final step: Select the top constraint of the Label and set its priority to `250`.

[image: Label priority to <code>250</code>]

[Link to the project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4JO_QKEBIHoanZtUTdmRFZ5T0E/view?usp=sharing)